# For each record in table, update column using min and max

Tags: sql

I'm very new to sql and I am having difficulty figuring out how to write my query to update one of my tables. I have a table called `stock_price` with the following fields:

`stock_symbol, date, open_price, daily_high, daily_low, close_price,` and `volume`.

The table is populated with 2 years (2012, 2013) worth of daily stock prices for every U.S. stock which equates to about 1.9 million records.

I'm looking to add two new fields called `year_high` and `year_low`.  For the 2013 records, I need to calculate and update these new fields using the existing data (min and max from `close_price` for the previous 365 days) in the table.  I'm really at a lost of how to tackle this so I hope someone can help get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to approach this using generic SQL to do the calculation:

```
select p.*,
       (select min(sp2.close_price)
        from stock_price sp2
        where sp2.stock_symbol = sp.stock_symbol and
              sp2.date between sp.date - 365 and sp.date
       ) as yearmin,
       (select max(sp2.close_price)
        from stock_price sp2
        where sp2.stock_symbol = sp.stock_symbol and
              sp2.date between sp.date - 365 and sp.date
       ) as yearmax
from stock_price sp;
```

Databases differ a bit on date arithmetic, so subtraction might not be sufficient.

If you have the columns in your table (or if you add them using `alter table`), you can update them as:

```
update stock_price
    set year_min = (select min(sp2.close_price)
                    from stock_price sp2
                    where sp2.stock_symbol = stock_price.stock_symbol and
                          sp2.date between stock_price.date - 365 and stock_price.date
                   ),
        year_max = (select max(sp2.close_price)
                    from stock_price sp2
                    where sp2.stock_symbol = stock_price.stock_symbol and
                          sp2.date between stock_price.date - 365 and stock_price.date
                   );
```

Note that both of these will put in values for the first 364 days, even though a full year is not available.

Answer (score 0):

update stock_price set year_high = (select max(close_price) where date between 'start_date' and 'end_date') where date between 'start_date' and 'end_date' ;

update stock_price set year_low = (select min(close_price) where date between 'start_date' and 'end_date') where date between 'start_date' and 'end_date' ;

There is going to be redundant data in the table doing it this way , an alternative approach would be to have a separate table for year wise min and max